# Within Google Script, force Sheet and new Form to sync with each other

Tags: google-apps-script

i've got a script that involves (among other things), creating a Form, using an existing Sheet as output, building the questions, and submitting a sample response. sometimes, it works exactly as expected; once the script is complete (rather, during its progress), you can see the questions in the first row of the sheet, and the response in row 2. however, sometimes, it takes several minutes for them to appear, despite the form always having the questions (and even response) properly visible in that interface

is there a command for forcing the Sheet and Form to sync up? SpreadsheetApp.flush() is helpful in other spots of my script, but not here

Comment: Does your script require the example response to continue? If not, don't worry about delays in Google's synchronization that you cannot control.

Comment: the script doesn't entirely require it, but the context might. i'm using this script to ship out a sheet/form combo to users, and i just know a bunch of people will freak out if errors pop up on functions that depend on the response. it's more for my sanity than anything, so if necessary i can just brace myself...but i figured i'd ask, just in case!

Comment: To solve the issue in your comment, wrap your code in a try/catch block so you can either silently ignore the errors or display a user-friendly error message.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch